# Find the index of a nested dict within a list base on the dict's nested value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

i have a list of dicts

```py
[{"id":1, "name": "jane", "contact": {"email": "jane@gmail.com", "phone": "8179482938"}},
{"id":2, "name": "john", "contact": {"email": "john@gmail.com", "phone": "8179482937"}},
{"id":3, "name": "june", "contact": {"email": "june@gmail.com", "phone": "8179482936"}}]
```

how can i find the index of jane given only her phone number (8179482938)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an index, you can do (`lst` is your list from question):

```
idx = next(i for i, d in enumerate(lst) if d["contact"]["phone"] == "8179482938")
print(idx)
```

Prints:

```
0
```

Answer (score 1):

It's rather straightforward.  You loop through the list until you find the one you want.

```
def get_name(phone):
    for i, row in enumerate(list_of_dicts):
        if row['contact']['phone'] == phone:
            return i
```

Comment: Bah, I thought I read "how can I find jane.'.  I'll fix.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
book = [{"id":1, "name": "jane", "contact": {"email": "jane@gmail.com", "phone": "8179482938"}},
{"id":2, "name": "john", "contact": {"email": "john@gmail.com", "phone": "8179482937"}},
{"id":3, "name": "june", "contact": {"email": "june@gmail.com", "phone": "8179482936"}}]

for item in book:
    if item['contact']['phone'] == '8179482938':
        print(item['id'])
```